# How can use ephemeral message?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import pandas as pd
import FinanceDataReader as fdr
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import locale

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents=intents)

player = {}
confirm = {}

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Login Bot: {bot.user}')

@bot.command()
async def 주식가격(ctx, *name):
    stock_t = ' '.join(name) 
    df_krx = fdr.StockListing('KRX')
    df_krx.to_csv('stock.csv')
    symbols = pd.read_csv('./stock.csv')
    try:
        code = symbols[symbols['Name'] == stock_t]['Code'].iloc[0]
        url = f"https://finance.naver.com/item/main.nhn?code={code}"
        result = requests.get(url)
        bs_obj = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'html.parser')
        no_today = bs_obj.find('p', {"class": "no_today"})
        blind_now = no_today.find("span", {"class": "blind"})
        await ctx.send(f'{stock_t}의 현재 가격: {blind_now.text}원', ephemeral=True)
    except IndexError:
        await ctx.send(f"주식 이름 '{stock_t}'을 찾을 수 없습니다.", ephemeral=True)
    except Exception as e:
        await ctx.send(f"오류가 발생했습니다: {e}", ephemeral=True)
```

ephemeral is not working. How can solve this? not good at English sorry.

The above code is functioning correctly, and ephemeral messages are working as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation says,

> [ephemeral] is only applicable in contexts with an interaction.

Link: [send](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.send)

What this means is that this only works with [discord.Interaction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#interaction), which include [discord.ui.Button](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#id1), [discord.ui.Select](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#select), [app_commands.command](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.app_commands.Command).

This is an example of an ephemeral message through a slash command.

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

@tree.command(name="mycommand", description="Command description")
async def mycommand_callback(interaction: discord.Interaction): #  This is the context, discord.Interaction
    await interaction.response.send_message(content="Hello World!",
                                            ephemeral=True)
```

This would send an ephemeral message. Since you are using it in the context of
[commands.Context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context), the ephemeral parameter in the [send](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.send) method is ignored.